# Laravel: No query results for model

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5

i have a PageController, which is displaying the content of a page, but first i need to check, that the entered url exists and only in that case i will display the page.

Unfortunately if the searched page, does not exist it throws me an Exception:

```
NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 103:
No query results for model [App\Models\PageTranslation].
```

Here is my code, i am trying to redirect if nothing found to Error 404, but it still gives me the NotFoundHttpException.

```
public function show($page) {

    $lang = Lang::getLocale();

    $page = $this->page_translation->where('slug', '=', $page)->where('lang', '=', $lang)->firstOrFail();

    if(!$page) {
        App::abort(404);
    }

    return view('front.page.show', compact('page'));

}
```

How can i redirect in that case the user to the Error 404 page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `first()` instead of `firstOrFail()`. `firstOrFail()` fails (throw 404) immediately if there are no matching data and won't go through rest of the code, whereas `first()` returns `null` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would catch the exception and then redirect:

```
public function show($page) {
        $lang = Lang::getLocale();
        try{
            $page = $this->page_translation->where('slug', '=', $page)->where('lang', '=', $lang)->firstOrFail();
        } catch (\NotFoundHttpException $e) {
            //maybe log the error for debugging purposes
            App::abort(404);
        }
        return view('front.page.show', compact('page'));
    }
```